# css Carousel Bootstrap "da-dots" edit

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

Dear CSS/Bootstrap Community,

I'm currently learning the design aspects of bootstrap, how to edit, etc etc

I have tried a number of different changes, but what I want to achieve still alludes me.

Now, this is my CSS:

```
.da-dots span {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    border-radius: 0px;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.13);
    margin: 3px;
    cursor: pointer;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0) inset, 1px 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,0);
    border: 2px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.0);
}
```

Now this is what this looks like:

[image]

As you can see, for my active da-dot, I have a white circle. Now, what I would like to change to is:

Active da-dot: like it is now, minus the background shading.

Unactive da-dot: same size circle, except it is not filled in.

Essentially I would like to achieve something like this:

[image]

For completeness, here is the html of the section in question:

```
<section id="home">
    <div class="banner-container">
        <img src="images/banner-bg.gif" alt="banner" />
        <div class="container banner-content">
            <div id="da-slider" class="da-slider">
                <div class="da-slide">
                    <h2>Webdesigner</h2>
                    <p>Amazing free responsive website for free, enjoy!!!</p>
                    <div class="da-img"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="da-slide">
                    <h2>UX/UI Developer</h2>
                    <p>I develop website using Bootstrap front-end framework..</p>
                    <div class="da-img"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="da-slide">
                    <h2>HTML5/CSS3</h2>
                    <p>HTML5 is a markup language used for structuring and presenting Web.</p>
                    <div class="da-img"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="da-slide">
                    <h2>JavaScript/jQuery</h2>
                    <p>jQuery: Write Less, Do More...</p>
                    <div class="da-img"></div>
                </div>
            <!--  <nav class="da-arrows">
                    <span class="da-arrows-prev"></span>
                    <span class="da-arrows-next"></span>
                </nav> -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: This is exactly like the bootstrap carousel, why don't you use those classes? [caroussel](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel)

Comment: @YerkoPalma Hi Yerko. Well, the reason being is that the bootstrap carousel scrolls through three images, where what mine does is scroll through three different text intros whilst keeping the background image the same.

Comment: It's fine, but you could just copy and paste bootstrap source for that specific elements. Their define the `.carousel-indicators` css class, here is the [less source](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/less/carousel.less#L173) for that class

Comment: Can create stacksnippets, jsfiddle ?

Comment: your added html is missing the 'da-dots'

Answer (score 0):

For this HTML:

```
<div class="da-dots">
    <span class="dotbox">
        <span class="dot"></span>
    </span>
    <span class="dotbox">
        <span class="dot"></span>
    </span>
    <span class="dotbox">
        <span class="dot active"></span>
    </span>
    <span class="dotbox">
        <span class="dot"></span>
    </span>
</div>
```

This CSS:

```
.dotbox {
    width:16px;
    height:16px;
    display:inline-block;
    padding:3px;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.13);
    text-align:center;
}

.dot.active{
    background:#ffffff;
}

.dot{
    width:10px;
    height:10px;
    display:inline-block;
    border-radius:50%;
    border:1px solid #ffffff;   
}
```

See [this demo fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/ke68mzgv/1/)

**Or without the shaded boxes, for this HTML:**

```
<div class="da-dots">
    <span class="dot"></span>
    <span class="dot"></span>
    <span class="dot active"></span>
    <span class="dot"></span>
</div>
```

This CSS:

```
.dot {
   width:16px;
    height:16px;
    display:inline-block;
    border-radius:50%;
    border:1px solid #ffffff;
}

.dot.active{
    background:#ffffff;
}
```

See [this demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ke68mzgv/)

HTH

Answer (score 0):

Easiest solution would be to use bootstrap's [carousel-indicators class](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel)

```
<ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
</ol>
```

Comment: And where is your html?

Comment: @MichaelRoberts: I see you've edit your post. Where's the `da-dots` class?

Answer (score 0):

As I said, the best would be to copy and paste [bootstrap](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/less/carousel.less#L173) souce code, adapted to your markup

for this html

```
<div class="da-dots">
    <span ></span>
    <span class="active"></span>
    <span ></span>
</div>
```

and this css

```
.da-dots {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
  left: 50%;
  z-index: 15;
  width: 60%;
  margin-left: -30%;
  padding-left: 0;
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center; 
  background: #777;
  padding: 10px 0;
}

.da-dots span {
  display: inline-block;
  width:  10px;
  height: 10px;
  margin: 1px;
  text-indent: -999px;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;    
  background-color: #000 \9; // IE8
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0); // IE9
}
.da-dots .active {
  margin: 0;
  width:  12px;
  height: 12px;
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

you have [**this**](http://jsfiddle.net/yerkopalma/11py1snp/) result